# Rubymine: Ctrl + Click not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

Recently I have updated my Rails and Ruby（1.9.3 to 2.1) version, using a newer version of RailsInstaller
After that, in `RubyMine`, when I use `ctrl + click` to jump from code to code, sometimes it's not working.

**CASE1**

I have included some constants in `initializers/resources_constants.rb`, 
So I can use them like `constants = RESOURCES_CONSTANT::SOME_CONSTANT`.

It used to work fine. When `ctrl + click`, I can jump directly into the `resources_constants.rb`. But now, I can not switch to it.

The code itself is still running very well, and I can still use the constants defined in that file.

**CASE2**

`require 'nokogiri'` works fine, I can jump to it.

**CASE3**

`video.get_hits`. It's a instance method defined in `Video.rb` model. I cannot jump to it, but the code still works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kinda the Jetbrains "nuclear option", but it's worked for me every time this type of thing happens (usually after ruby version updates).

1. Completely close all running instances of RubyMine
2. In the root directory of the project in question, delete the hidden `.idea` directory
3. Reopen your project in RubyMine as normal

Comment: Still not working. I find that it could jump within the file. But cannot jump between file. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem few months earlier after updating the Rubymine. I contacted their support and it was resolved by:

Clicking on **File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart**
It will invalidate your cache build in previous version and index it as per new.

Comment: Restarted RubyMine after that?

Answer (score 0):

Hi seeing any rubyfile name `resources_constants.rb` I guess it has a class named `ResourcesConstants` so any contant defined in that class is `SOME_CONSTANT = 'some value'`

 To access that constant we need to use namespacing `operator(::)` like

```
ResourcesConstants::SOME_CONSTANT
```

now your `ctrl+click` might work.
and I suggest you to restart the server everytime you modify any config files or constants files

Comment: Do you notice the `case3`? Instance Method.

Comment: well in case 3, the variable `video` might not be directly assigned a value. can you show me how this variable is initialized? RubyMine cannot find the reference if assignment is very complex. Specially if helper methods are involved